# Saving to clipboard in a Python script running as shell command

Tags: shell-command

The following python script successfully copies a given string into the clipboard when run from Ubuntu shell:

```
import os
text = 'The text to be copied to the clipboard.'
os.system("echo -n {s} | xsel -b".format(s=text))
```

However, when I execute the script from Emacs as follows, it does not work:

```
(call-process-shell-command "clipboard.py &" nil 0)
```

What is special about the script run with `call-process-shell-command` and how do I work around the problem so my Python script would be able to use the clipboard?

**EDIT:** In addition, `(shell-command-to-string "python clipboard.py")` freezes.

Comment: Why not execute the source buffer? Works for me.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler Do you mean like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25687205/2725810? First, I did not know about this option, so thank you! Second, the script is a server used by the commands that I implemented in ELisp. This server is supposed to run in the background without distracting the user. Can I achieve this with the approach that you are suggesting? Lastly, even if this works, I am curious what causes the problem described in the original question of mine.

Comment: Maybe try (call-process-shell-command "python clipboard.py &" nil 0)

Comment: @AndreasRöhler This does not make the clipboard work either. Note that my python script runs just fine. The only thing that's not working is clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `-i` option of `xsel`, which tells `xsel` to read standard input, fixes it. I do not know why it worked without this option outside of `Emacs`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Say what that option does?

Comment: @Drew Done as per the request.